# displaying records in search results with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following ajax.js, which I must use:

```
var xmlRequest = null;
    function ajax(url, parametersArray, callbackFunction, fcnVars) {
        if (xmlRequest != null) {
        if (xmlRequest.readyState == 2 || xmlRequest.readyState == 3) {
            xmlRequest.abort();
            xmlRequest = null;
           }
        }
        if (parametersArray == null)
            parameters = "";
        else
            parameters = formatParameters(parametersArray);
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            xmlRequest = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
            xmlRequest.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlRequest.status == 200) {
                    if (xmlRequest.responseText) {
                        callbackFunction(xmlRequest.responseText, fcnVars);
                    }
                }
            }
        xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
        xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xmlRequest.send(parameters);
    }

    function formatParameters(parameters) {
        var i = 0;
        var param = "";
        for (index in parameters) {
            if (i==0) {
                param += index+"="+urlencode(parameters[index]);
            } else {
                param += "&"+index+"="+urlencode(parameters[index]);
            }
            i++; 
        }
    return param;
    }

    function urlencode(clearString) {
        clearString = encodeURI(clearString);
        clearString = clearString.replace('&', '%26');
        return clearString;
    }
```

and I have the following mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `dictionary` (
   `word` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`word`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

on the end, here is my search page:

```
<div id = "search">
    <form id="searchform" method="post">
    Search for Word: 
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="search_term" name="search_term"  />
    <input type="submit" id="cmdSearch" value="Search"  />
</form>
<div id="search_results"></div>
</div>
```

Now, I have to create a php function which will return an array with the words found in the table, using the above ajax.js

Results should be shown within the search_results div using ajax.

Of course, I will need a javascript code as well.

Anyone can help me to start to build this? I have done similar things with jquery,but now I must use this script, and I have no other way to do it.

Goal is to display the results in the php page without refresh.

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Update:

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

// add encoding here
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-7");

// include the database connection here
include 'config.php';
include 'openDb.php';
function findWords(){
    // sanitaze the user input
    $term = strip_tags(substr($_POST['search_term'],0, 100));
    $term = mysql_escape_string($term);

    // query the database. one fileld only, so nothing to optimize here
    $sql = "SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE word like '%$term%'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // set the string variable
    $string = '';

    // if resulta are found then populate the string variable
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
            // display the results here in bold and add a new line or break after each     result  
            $string[] = "<b>".$row->user_name."</b><br/>\n";
        }
    } else {
        // if no results are found, inform the visitors...  
        $string[] = "No matches!";
    }
    // output the string
    return $string[];
```

Here is the javascript:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    ajax("findWord.php", {id:search_term}, function(result,params) {
    alert("result for ID: "+params.id+"\n\n"+result);
    }, {id:search_term});
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried building it yourself? What have you got stuck with?

Comment: well , I have done the php, except that I am not sure if it will works. my biggest problem is the javascript call

Comment: So what have you attempted to build the required javascript?

Comment: nothing yet... scratching my head where to start from

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rely on the `ajax` function which lets you access whatever it loaded in the callback function:

```
callbackFunction(xmlRequest.responseText, fcnVars);
```

And `ajax` explains how it should be called itself:

```
ajax(url, parametersArray, callbackFunction, fcnVars)
```

Even though parametersArray should actually be an object (`{index:value, i1:v2,...}`) rather than an array (`[val1, val2,...]`). `fcnVars` can be an object containing anything that you want passed on to the callback function.

This should work:

```
ajax("add_page.php", {id:535}, function(result,params) {
    alert("result for ID: "+params.id+"\n\n"+result);
}, {id:535});
```

Comment: I have no id at all..I should use the search_term instead I guess?

Comment: Try, if things don't work, research why; if you can't find anything after extensive looking and trying, ask on SO :)

Comment: no...doesn't work. I will add my php code above and my javascript as well, so please take a look on my question again.

Comment: Question is updated, can you please why it doesn't work? I am not getting any errors, just doesn't work.

Comment: SO is Stack Overflow. From looking at your trial code, it seems you need to brush up on some basic JS knowledge first of all. This tutorial might be of help (esp. heading "passing variables to functions"): http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/functions